# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'bool' shared_preferences

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

Trying to get this switch to still function as well as save and keep over app closure/reopen. Neither of these things is achieved and once the switch is activated, it will throw is an error when trying to change the switch back.

```
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'bool'
```

-

```
void onChange(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      brain.units = value;
    });
  }

  //Shared Prefs saver

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadValue();
  }

  _loadValue() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      units = (prefs.getBool('boolValue'));
    });
  }

  _setValue() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      units = (prefs.getBool('boolValue'));
      prefs.setBool('boolValue', units);
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: SwitchListTile(
          title: Text(this.unitName = brain.unitClass(),
          value: brain.units,
          secondary: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.balanceScale, color: kIconColor),
          onChanged: (
            bool value,
          ) {
            onChange(value && _setValue());
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what happened, tried solutions given. They worked temporarily then stopped working, now the switch doesn't work at all. Reverted to an old version from version control and only one page works with the value changing as intended originally.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem ist that the _setValue() in

```
onChange(value && _setValue());
```

is not returning anything.

You should try to place this call on top of the onChange() or let it return true at the end.

```
 _setValue() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      units = (prefs.getBool('boolValue'));
      prefs.setBool('boolValue', units);
    });
    return true
  }
```

or if it's not neccessary that _setValue() is done before the onChange(value) call

```
onChanged: (bool value) {
     _setValue();
     onChange(value);
},
```

Comment: Have you tried to return true at the end? value && _setValue() can't be evaluated to a bool in your case.

Comment: Thank you, this works and I no longer get the error message, but the switch changes back after closing the app.

Comment: Yes I added return true at the end.

Comment: Then you need to load the sharedpreferences and get the value before you build your switch (Maybe with a FutureBuilder) and pass the value into it.

Comment: If you need help with that I could give an example later the day

Comment: That would be great, thank you.

Unfortunately, since trying these solutions the switch has stopped responding on most of the app. It's no longer doing its intended purpose for about 90% of its usages. Hopefully, I can get this sorted before then, as I'm not sure what's causing this new issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onChange` is expecting a `bool` as an argument and you are passing in `value && _setValue()`. Are you sure that this evaluates to a `bool`?

It looks like the `_setValue` is returning a `Future<dynamic>` and this together with the `&&` does not evaluate to a `bool` and is triggering the assertion error, I suspect.

You could move the `_setValue` call to your `onChange` method and then just call that with the new value or separate the call to `onChange` from the one to `_setValue`:

```
onChanged: (bool value,) {
     _setValue();
     onChange(value);
},
```

Comment: Thank you, this works and I no longer get the error message, but the switch changes back after closing the app.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code as following,

```
onChanged: (bool value,) asyc
          {
            var isValueSet=await _setValue();
            onChange(value && isValueSet);
          },
```

Here, _setValue() you are using for passing inside onChange() method has Future return type. which means you have to wait till your _setValue() is not been evaluated. So try assigning the future value as above.

This will solve your issue.